# Does the taxi waiting time impact the taxi fare when taking a taxi from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)'s taxi stand?

Tags: taxis, taiwan, fares, taipei, tpe

Does the taxi waiting time impact the taxi fare when taking a taxi from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)'s taxi stand?

I see the waiting time on my taxi ride receipt, which makes me wonder:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this happens in Taipei, but a moderately common scam at airports is for taxis to turn on the meter before you get in, racking up extra charges.  In places with flat fees for the first km or two, drivers who play it right can have the meter shown the expected base when you board, yet they've already clocked up 1.9km so the meter starts spinning immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. Though:

1. The waiting time refers to the time the taxi spent waiting (or moving very slowly) in traffic and lights (after the flag is down), but not the time it wait for the passengers to turn up before the flag is down, and
2. It doesn't cost much as compared to how much the taxi charge when it moves.

---

The department of transport, Taoyuan City gave [the following notice](https://traffic.tycg.gov.tw/businessD/post/upt.aspx?p0=72439) regarding taxi fare (translation mine):

> 一、本市計程車運價收費方式如下：
>   (一)起程收費：1,250公尺95元。
>   (二)續程收費：每250公尺加收5元。
>   (三)延滯計時收費：時速5公里以下，每150秒加收5元。
>   (四)台灣桃園國際機場排班計程車依本運價加收15%停留服務費。
>   (五)春節加成運價：
>   1.收費標準：於實施期間，除依核定運價，本市(臺灣桃園國際機場排班計程車除外)計程車按趟次計費，無論搭乘距離每趟次加收50元： 機場排班計程車按趟次計費，無論搭乘距離每趟次加收100元。
>   2.實施期間：自除夕前2天至國定年假結束期間(如不足10天以國定年假最後1天(含)往前推算10天)。
>   (六)日夜間同價。
>   (七)本次公告係修正部分文字，相關計程車運價未作調整。
>
> The taxi fare in this [Taoyuan] city is charged as follow:
>   1. Initial charge: First 1,250m - NTD 95
>   2. Subsequent charge: Every 250m thereafter - NTD 5
>   3. Delayed time [waiting] charge: Speed below 5km/h - NTD 5 per 150 seconds
>   4. Journeys from taxi stands in Taiwan Taoyuan Intl Airport are subject to 15% surcharge.
>   5. [Surcharge during Chinese New Year that is irrelevant to this question]
>   6. Same fare during the day and evening
>   7. This notice only modifies the wording of the fare schedule, but not the fare.

Note the other answer links to a fare schedule provided by Taipei City. TPE falls in the jurisdiction of Taoyuan City and hence any taxi you board is likely to follow Taoyuan City's fare schedule.

For your journey, the fare is charged as follow:

- First 1,250m: NTD 95
- Next 169x 250m: NTD 5 x 169 = NTD 845 (That brings you to 43.5km, with the last 0.2km not charged)
- Waiting time (2x 150 seconds): NTD 5 x 2 = NTD 10

This gives a running total of NTD 950. Adding the 15% surcharge (NTD 142.5, with a round up NTD 145) and the freeway surcharge (30 NTD) leads to the final fare of NTD 1,125.

Answer (score 6):

That looks like it should be the cost for being stuck in traffic.  It's not specific to the airport, just a common way taxi fares work to balance distance and time.

From [this government site](https://english.gov.taipei/News_Content.aspx?n=ADAE9018C6CFA1FE&sms=5B794C46F3CDE718&s=BB2FB8006C15186B) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190927005043/https://english.gov.taipei/News_Content.aspx?n=ADAE9018C6CFA1FE&sms=5B794C46F3CDE718&s=BB2FB8006C15186B)) (numbers appear to be out of date, but it illustrates the general idea):

> (2) Prolonged metering: It’s NT$5 for every 100 seconds for slow-moving taxis at under 5km per hour.